# jQuery Mobile accordion widget auto height is not working

Tags: jquery, jquery-ui, jquery-mobile, accordion, jquery-ui-accordion

I am using the jQuery Mobile accordion widget with jQuery version 1.7.1 and jQueryMobile version 1.1.1. I would like the accordion, when expanded, to occupy a fixed space so that the rest of the page doesn't scroll down, just like the demo here: http://jqueryui.com/accordion/#default

I have tried using the 'accordion' options from jQuery but it seems that they are different. As it is now, the accordion panels change size depending on content and thus the content below the accordion constantly shifts.

Here is my code:

```
  <div data-role="collapsible-set">
    <div data-role="collapsible">
        <h3>Title 1</h3>
        <p>[content 1: very long]</p>
    </div>
    <div data-role="collapsible">
        <h3>Title 2</h3>
        <p>[content 2: normal length]</p>
    </div>
    <div data-role="collapsible">
        <h3>Title 3</h3>
        <p>[content 3: short]</p>
    </div>
    <div data-role="collapsible">
        <h3>Title 4</h3>
        <p>[content 4: short]</p>
    </div>
</div>
```

Thank you!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Do not confuse jQuery Ui accordion with a jQuery Mobile accordion, they do not have anything in common.

jQuery Mobile accordion can be forced to use fixed height with some css changes:

```
.ui-collapsible-content {
    height: 50px !important;
    overflow-y:scroll !important;
}
```

Live **jsFiddle** example: http://jsfiddle.net/Gajotres/YvhLk/

Remove  **overflow-y:scroll !important;** if you do not want a scroll bar.

Comment: This is awesome thank you! Do you know how I would set it to automatically expand to the largest of the content sections? The content is dynamic.